# Waypoints not responding

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I am failing to see why I cannot get waypoints to work.  Code is below, what am I missing (it must be something small and simple)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.min.js"> </script>

<script>
             $('#waypoint').waypoint(function () {
            alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
        }, {
            offset: '100%'
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="height: 1500px">Scroll down</div>
<div id="waypoint">Waypoint</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're including the jquery library, which is required.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.min.js"> </script>
```